# Python and products file XML

Tags: python, xml

I'm using python and I need to find `sku`, `min-order-qty` and `step-quantity` for each occurence of `sku`.

Input file is:

```
<product sku="1235997403">
  <sku>1235997403</sku>
  <name xml:lang="fr-FR">Huile pour entretien des destructeurs de documents HSM</name>
  <short-description xml:lang="fr-FR">Flacon 250 ml. Colis de 1 flacon.</short-description>
  <category-links>
    <category-link name="20319647o.rjpf_20320074o.rjpf" domain="RAJA-FR-WEB-0092-21" default = "1" hotdeal = "0"/>
  </category-links>
  <online>1</online>
  <quantity unit="pcs">
    <min-order-quantity>1</min-order-quantity>
    <step-quantity>1</step-quantity>
  </quantity>
....
</product>
....
```

I try to use lxml but fail to get min-order-qty and step-quantity

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('./ST2CleanCourt.xml')
elem = tree.getroot()
for  child in elem:
        print (child.attrib["sku"])
```

---

I tried to use the 2 solutions below. It works but I need to read the file so I write

```
from lxml import etree
import codecs
f=codecs.open('./ST2CleanCourt.xml','r','utf-8')
fichier = f.read()
tree = etree.fromstring(fichier)

for child in tree:
    print ('sku:', child.attrib['sku'])
    print ('min:', child.find('.//min-order-quantity').text)
```

and I always get this error 
    print ('min:', child.find('.//min-order-quantity').text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

what is wrong ?

Comment: Show us the code you're using.

Comment: `<product>` is your root element.  It has no child elements with a sku attribute.  It does have a child element with a _tag name_ xml, but tag names aren't the same as attributes.  (i.e. `<foo sku="bar">` vs. `<sku>bar</sku>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using more then 1 product and root node of products you can find this:

```
x = """
<products>
<product sku="1235997403">
  <sku>1235997403</sku>
  <name xml:lang="fr-FR">Huile pour entretien des destructeurs de documents HSM</name>
  <short-description xml:lang="fr-FR">Flacon 250 ml. Colis de 1 flacon.</short-description>
  <category-links>
    <category-link name="20319647o.rjpf_20320074o.rjpf" domain="RAJA-FR-WEB-0092-21" default = "1" hotdeal = "0"/>
  </category-links>
  <online>1</online>
  <quantity unit="pcs">
    <min-order-quantity>1</min-order-quantity>
    <step-quantity>1</step-quantity>
  </quantity>
</product>
<product sku="997403">
  <sku>1235997403</sku>
  <name xml:lang="fr-FR">Huile pour entretien des destructeurs de documents HSM</name>
  <short-description xml:lang="fr-FR">Flacon 250 ml. Colis de 1 flacon.</short-description>
  <category-links>
    <category-link name="20319647o.rjpf_20320074o.rjpf" domain="RAJA-FR-WEB-0092-21" default = "1" hotdeal = "0"/>
  </category-links>
  <online>1</online>
  <quantity unit="pcs">
    <min-order-quantity>5</min-order-quantity>
    <step-quantity>7</step-quantity>
  </quantity>
</product>
</products>
"""

from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring(x) 
for  child in tree:
    print ("sku:", child.attrib["sku"])
    print ("min:", child.find(".//min-order-quantity").text)  # looks for  node below
    print ("step:" ,child.find(".//step-quantity").text)  # child with the given name
```

Essentially you look for any node below child that has the correct name and print its text.

Output:

```
sku:1235997403
min:1
step:1
sku:997403
min:5
step:7
```

Doku:  http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elementpath

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **xpath** method to get the required values.

**Example:**

```
from lxml import etree

a = """<product sku="1235997403">
  <sku>1235997403</sku>
  <name xml:lang="fr-FR">Huile pour entretien des destructeurs de documents HSM</name>
  <short-description xml:lang="fr-FR">Flacon 250 ml. Colis de 1 flacon.</short-description>
  <category-links>
    <category-link name="20319647o.rjpf_20320074o.rjpf" domain="RAJA-FR-WEB-0092-21" default = "1" hotdeal = "0"/>
  </category-links>
  <online>1</online>
  <quantity unit="pcs">
    <min-order-quantity>1</min-order-quantity>
    <step-quantity>1</step-quantity>
  </quantity>
</product>
"""

tree = etree.fromstring(a)
tags = tree.xpath('/product')

for b in tags:
    print b.attrib["sku"]
    min_order = b.xpath("//quantity/min-order-quantity")
    print min_order[0].text
    step_quality = b.xpath("//quantity/step-quantity")
    print step_quality[0].text
```

**Output:**

```
1235997403
1
1
```